# Reactive form validation error message not updating in UI of CustomElement ANGULAR

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular-reactive-forms, custom-element

I have created custom elements in my Angular application. That custom elements have Reactive forms. When form validation is happening, the UI is not updating. The validation functions are triggering. But, the error messages are not showing/updating in the UI.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-field">
    <input class="text-input" [type]="field.type" [attr.maxLength]="field.maxLength" [formControlName]="field.key"
        [ngClass]="{ disable: !field.editable }" value="{{ field.value }}" [placeholder]="field.placeholder"
        [autofocus]="field.focus" />
    <img class="input-lable-image" src="assets/images/svgs/{{
        field.labelImage }}.svg" *ngIf="field.labelImage" />
    <div *ngIf="field.updateOn == 'blur'">
        <div *ngIf="(!formGroup.controls[field.key].value) && formGroup.controls[field.key].touched && !formSubmitAttempt"
            class="error-msg">
            {{ field.emptyValueMessage }}
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="formGroup.controls[field.key].value && formGroup.controls[field.key].status == 'INVALID' && !formSubmitAttempt && formGroup.controls[field.key].touched"
            class="error-msg">
            {{ field.validationValue }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div *ngIf="(!formGroup.controls[field.key].value) &&
                formSubmitAttempt" class="error-msg">
            {{ field.emptyValueMessage }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="formGroup.controls[field.key].value &&
        isInvalid(formGroup.controls[field.key], formSubmitAttempt)" class="error-msg">

        {{ field.validationValue }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help me solve this.

Thanks...

**UPDATE:** Code snippet

```
signupFormInputsConfig = [
    {
      type: "text",
      placeholder: "Enter your full name",
      label: "Name",
      required: true,
      key: "userName",
      labelImage: "user",
      value: "",
      controlType: "inputText",
      editable : true,
      emptyValueMessage:"Please enter valid name",
      validationValue:"Please enter your name",
      validators: [Validators.required],
      focus : true
    }]
```

**Converting to reactive form:**

```
toReactiveForm(inputs: Array<{}>) {
    let group = {};
    inputs.forEach(input => {
        if (input["controlType"] === "formGroup") {
            group[input["key"]] = this.toReactiveForm(input["formInputs"]);
        } else if (input["controlType"] === "formArray") {
            let formArray = this.formBuilder.array([]);
            input["formInputs"].forEach(formGroup => {
                let fGroup = this.toReactiveForm(formGroup["formInputs"]);
                formArray.push(fGroup);
            });
            group[input["key"]] = formArray;
        } else if (input["controlType"] === "submitButton") {
            //Don't add to form Group
        } else {
            group[input["key"]] = [input["value"] || "", input["validators"]];
        }
    });
    return this.formBuilder.group(group);
}
```

**Validation functions:**

```js
static validateMobile(control: FormControl): any {
    var regex = /^[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$/;
    var found = regex.test(control.value);
    return found ? null : { mobile: true };
}

  static validateConsentPin(control: FormControl): any {
    var regex = /^[0-9]{6}$/;
    var found = regex.test(control.value);
    return found ? null : { consentPin: true };
}


  static validateCRN(number): any {
    var regex = /^[0-9A-Za-z]{6,}$/;
    var found = regex.test(number);
    return found ? true : false;
}
```

Validations are triggering but, UI is not updating.

Comment: Can you post the component code?

Comment: @NimishDavidMathew, I updated the question. Please look into it.

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz for the same will be easy to debug